# Objective - C - Usage of << in enumeration

Tags: objective-c, c, typedef, enumeration

I can see in Apple's documentation that enumerations are sometimes defined like this

```
enum {
UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop = 1 << 0,
UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom = 1 << 1
}
```

What does the << mean?

Comment: While everyone explained what it is technically and what it does, I'll just try to noobify it. Take a variable with for example `4 bits`, where it can have bit values between `0000` and `1111`. You could see this as switches, they are either `on (1)` or `off (0)`. To toggle the third switch (right to left) you have to take a `1` and `shift` it two steps to the left. Remember that every `"flag"` should (in most cases) toggle just one switch, so `1<<1 == 1, 1<<2 == 2, 1<<3 == 4`, so don't put a flag like `MyVar = 3` in there, because `3` is `0011` bit wise, toggling two switches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is simply left bit shift. So this means `1<<0` = `1` for instance. And `1<<1` is two. Maybe the author chose this way to initialize the enumeration to emphasize on the fact that `UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop` has only the least significant bit on and `UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom` has only the second to least significant bit on. I guess the usage for this enumeration is to somehow later form bitmasks.

Comment: After googling based on your answer, I found this helpful topic too: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/12/bit-masks/

Answer (score 3):

It's the [bitwise shift left](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Bitwise_operators) operator. It's used to create values having a single bit set, very common when combination through bitwise OR is intended.

For those values, you might later say:

```
const int top_and_bottom = UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop | UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom;
```

which would result in `top_and_bottom` being set to 3 (binary 11<sub>2</sub>).

Answer (score 1):

`<<` stands for left shift.

It shifts the binary to specified bits, as `4<<1` will be `8` and `4<<2` will be `16`.
Each left shift makes the value multiplied by 2.

1<<0 will be 1 while 1<<1 will be 2.

Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336xbhcz.aspx)